# which one is better to wrap AFNetworking functions in one file or use it in separate files,

Tags: ios, coding-style, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking as network library. There are two different coding styles and I don't know which one is better.

1. Wrap all functions that associated to network to one file.
   For example, I have a singleton file called API.m, and I wrapped `login` function as below:

   ```
   - (void) login:(NSString *)username withPassword:(NSString *)password
     andCompletionBlock:(void(^)(NSString*))block andFailBlock:(void(^)())failBlock
   {
     NSMutableString *url = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
     [url appendString:LOGINURL];

     NSURL* nurl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
     NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nurl];
     AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
     [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     NSString *requestTmp = [NSString stringWithString:operation.responseString];
       block(requestTmp);
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
       failBlock();
     }];
     [operation start];
   }
   ```

Then in `LoginViewController`, I can call this function to do my login job:

```
    [[ServerAPI Instance] login:@"hello" withPassword:@"world" 
    andCompletionBlock:^(NSString *str) {} failBlock^(){}];
```

2. Write the network process code directly in separate view controllers.

Which one is a better coding style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating separate models to handle your API layer is always going to be better than writing networking code in your view controllers. This is especially true when you want to use the same networking call in more than one place.

With that said, there's probably a better way to write your networking instead of a blanket, multi-use singleton. Consider creating individual models such as a `User` model whose instance represents a logged in `User`, and also has convenient methods for login, logout, credential saving, refreshing, etc. Therefore you keep code relevant to a user within a the user class.

Comment: That'a really smart idea. How about this: create a `User` model and a network singleton, and call network functions in `User` instead of ViewController. One of the advantages of writing networking code in one file is that if I need to change network library, I just have to modify one file. Do you think that's a good way?

Comment: A better way would be instead wrap the network library altogether if you're worried about changing it in the future (instead of AFNetworking's POST, you call your own app's network method's POST, etc). To be honest though, in the long run, it's unlikely you'll be changing networking libraries too often haha.